# How to show duplicate data in multidimensional array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array

I am using Spout Excel reader to read Excel files from php code and saving into a multidimensional array in PHP variable,Array looks like this

```
$array = [
[
    'id[0]' => 'BX-78',
    'Name[0]' => 'XXX',
    'Address[0]' => 'YUUSATD'
],
[
    'id[1]' => 'BX-79',
    'Name[1]' => 'YYY',
    'Address[1]' => 'DHJSHDJGY'
],
[
    'id[2]' => 'BX-80',
    'Name[2]' => 'ZZZ',
    'Address[2]' => 'DDSDSDA'
]
[
    'id[3]' => 'BX-78',
    'Name[3]' => 'AAA',
    'Address[3]' => 'FSDSDS'
][
    'id[4]' => 'BX-81',
    'Name[4]' => 'XXX',
    'Address[4]' => 'DSDSDSD'
]];
```

Now i want to show duplicate data from above array using two keys `['id']` and `['name']` if id repeats show as duplicate data,

- If name repeats show that row as duplicate data if both are duplicate show as again duplicate row
- Otherwise it is unique row.

I have tried using multidimensional array sorting but it is using only one key to match data in rows.

```
foreach ($arrExcelData as $v) {
   if (isset($arrExcelData[$v[0]])) {
       // found duplicate
       continue;
    }
    // remember unique item
    $arrExcelData3[$v[0]] = $v;
}

// if you need a zero-based array, otheriwse work with $_data
$arrExcelData2 = array_values($arrExcelData3);
```

Edited : Expected Output Result :

Matching Rows:

```
Id       Name    Address
-------------------------
BX-78    XXX     YUUSATD
BX-78    AAA     DDSDSDA
BX-81    XXX     DSDSDSD`
```

Comment: So, you want to which where either the name or the ID exists in another element of the array?

Comment: Hello Qirel Thanks for reply,

Comment: See i want to find duplicate enteries using two key/parameters ['id'] and ['name'] if i find duplicate i want to show that data

Comment: My point is, is it duplicate if both the ID and name is the same, i.e. you have two rows with the ID `BX-78` **and** the name `XXX`? Or, if either is found multiple times?

Comment: Yeah, basically, please provide the expected result from that input you shared.

Comment: Here 'id[0]' => 'BX-78',
    'Name[0]' => 'XXX',
    'Address[0]' => 'YUUSATD' And 'id[3]' => 'BX-78',
    'Name[3]' => 'AAA',
    'Address[3]' => 'FSDSDS' is **duplicate** because i want to match parameter by both using 'OR' Condition Also 'id[0]' => 'BX-78',
    'Name[0]' => 'XXX',
    'Address[0]' => 'YUUSATD'  is duplicate with 'id[4]' => 'BX-81',
    'Name[4]' => 'XXX',
    'Address[4]' => 'DSDSDSD'

Comment: In first case id is matching and in second case name is matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list the duplicate values, I think the address of the second match should be `FSDSDS` as there is not item with name `AAA` and value `DDSDSDA`:

```
BX-78    AAA     FSDSDS
```

If that is the case, what you could do is to first use a double foreach to mark the arrays that contain a duplicate id or name by for example adding a property named `id` and `name` except when the array is itself in the second loop.

After this loop, you can tell which arrays are the duplicate ones. Instead of using a corresponding index 0 as in `id[0]`, I have used reset and next so it is not tied to these indexes.

To get the filtered result you could use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) to check for the array keys and unset them.

For example:

```
foreach ($array as $index => $a) {
    foreach ($array as $v) {
        if ($v === $a) continue;
        if (reset($v) === reset($a)) $array[$index]["id"] = "duplicate";
        if (next($v) === next($a)) $array[$index]["name"] = "duplicate";
    }
}

$array = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    if (array_key_exists("id", $item) || array_key_exists("name", $item)) {
        unset($item["id"], $item["name"]);
        $carry[] = $item;
    }
    return $carry;
}, []);

print_r($array);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id[0]] => BX-78
            [Name[0]] => XXX
            [Address[0]] => YUUSATD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id[3]] => BX-78
            [Name[3]] => AAA
            [Address[3]] => FSDSDS
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id[4]] => BX-81
            [Name[4]] => XXX
            [Address[4]] => DSDSDSD
        )

)
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/ed6dK)

Answer (score 0):

I've this very pragmatic approach:

```
$spout_output = [
[
    'id[0]' => 'BX-78',
    'Name[0]' => 'XXX',
    'Address[0]' => 'YUUSATD'
],
[
    'id[1]' => 'BX-79',
    'Name[1]' => 'YYY',
    'Address[1]' => 'DHJSHDJGY'
],
[
    'id[2]' => 'BX-80',
    'Name[2]' => 'ZZZ',
    'Address[2]' => 'DDSDSDA'
],
[
    'id[3]' => 'BX-78',
    'Name[3]' => 'AAA',
    'Address[3]' => 'FSDSDS'
],
[
    'id[4]' => 'BX-81',
    'Name[4]' => 'XXX',
    'Address[4]' => 'DSDSDSD'
]];

// store id to row, and name to row mappings.
// id and name will be keys, value will be an array of indexes of the array $spout_output
$id_to_rows = array();
$name_to_rows = array();

$duplicate_ids = array();
$duplicate_names = array();

foreach($spout_output as $row => $data)
{
    $key_id = 'id['.$row.']';
    $key_name = 'Name['.$row.']';

    if(!isset($data[$key_id]))
        continue;

    $value_id = $data[$key_id];
    $value_name = $data[$key_name];

    if(!isset($id_to_rows[$value_id]))
    {
        $id_to_rows[$value_id] = array();
    }
    else
    {
        if(!isset($duplicate_ids[$value_id]))
        {
            $duplicate_ids[$value_id] = $id_to_rows[$value_id];
        }

        $duplicate_ids[$value_id][] = $row;
    }

    if(!isset($name_to_rows[$value_name]))
    {
        $name_to_rows[$value_name] = array();
    }
    else
    {
        if(!isset($duplicate_names[$value_name]))
        {
            $duplicate_names[$value_name] = $name_to_rows[$value_name];
        }

        $duplicate_names[$value_name][] = $row;
    }

    $id_to_rows[$value_id][] = $row;
    $name_to_rows[$value_name][] = $row;
}

echo 'Duplicates:';
echo '<br>';
$shown_rows = array();
foreach($duplicate_ids as $id => $rows)
{
    foreach($rows as $nr)
    {
        echo $id . '|' . $spout_output[$nr]['Name['.$nr.']'] . '|' . $spout_output[$nr]['Address['.$nr.']'];
        echo '<br>';
        $shown_rows[] = $nr;
    }
}

foreach($duplicate_names as $name => $rows)
{
    foreach($rows as $nr)
    {
        // if already shown above, skip this row
        if(in_array($nr, $shown_rows))
            continue;

        echo $spout_output[$nr]['id['.$nr.']'] . '|' . $spout_output[$nr]['Name['.$nr.']'] . '|' . $spout_output[$nr]['Address['.$nr.']'];
        echo '<br>';
        $shown_rows[] = $nr;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Duplicates:
BX-78|XXX|YUUSATD
BX-78|AAA|FSDSDS
BX-81|XXX|DSDSDSD
```

I think your 'wanted output' contains an error in the address?
Anyway, with my code above I think you'll have enough mapped data to produce the output you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
$dupes = [];
$current = [];

foreach ($array as $index => $entry) {
  $idKey = "id[$index]";
  $nameKey = "Name[$index]";
  if (array_key_exists($entry[$idKey], $current)) {
    $dupes[] = [$entry, $current[$entry[$idKey]]];
  }
  elseif (array_key_exists($entry[$nameKey], $current)) {
    $dupes[] = [$entry, $current[$entry[$nameKey]]];
  }
  else {
    $current[$entry[$idKey]] = $current[$entry[$nameKey]] = $entry;
  }
}

print_r($dupes);
```

Which results in an array containing each set of duplicates (array of arrays):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id[3]] => BX-78
                    [Name[3]] => AAA
                    [Address[3]] => FSDSDS
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id[0]] => BX-78
                    [Name[0]] => XXX
                    [Address[0]] => YUUSATD
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id[4]] => BX-81
                    [Name[4]] => XXX
                    [Address[4]] => DSDSDSD
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id[0]] => BX-78
                    [Name[0]] => XXX
                    [Address[0]] => YUUSATD
                )

        )

)
```

**Demo here: https://3v4l.org/JAtNU**

Answer (score 0):

In case someone of you are searching unique values by key.

```
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
                    $temp_array = array();
                    $i = 0;
                    $key_array = array();
                    foreach($array as $val) {
                        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
                            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
                            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }
                    return $temp_array;
            }
```

- This function just takes multidimensional array and key value of field you need.
- Then takes value of given array one by one (smaller arrays).
- Then traverses given array and looking if taken key-value pair matches with given key.
- After that if taken key-value pair matches with given key function just inserts smaller array in temporary array (array with unique values).
- Don't forget to increment indexes of arrays ($i).
- Then return array you got (with unique values) after function ends work.